# Multiple Kafka Producers writing to the same topic - how to load balance consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

So I have a design where I have multiple producers P1, P2, P3, P4 ... PN writing to a single topic T1, that has 32 partitions.

On the other side I have up to 32 consumers on a single consumer group.

I would like to load balance my message consumption.
Reading the docs I could see 3 options:
 1. Define the partition myself (drawback I would have to know where the last message was sent or define a partition range for each Producer P)
 2. Define a key and leave the partition decision to the Kafka hash algorithm (drawback - load balancing would be defined on luck)
(As per Chris answer the load balancing should be left to hash algorithm) -the reality shows this does not provide equal distribution to the consumers as the consumers are bound to partitions and I would have to understand the hash algorithm to chose a good key - which to me sound the same as picking the partition (and that would have to be distributed over the producers) 
 My current code is using UUID as the key. The analysis of the partitions chosen, and consequently the consumers working, shows a distribution that may be far from being equal. I'm reproducing it below:

[image: Messages received by partition]
The image above shows the number of messages received by each partitions in a 5 minutes window using UUID as my key - at that point in time I had 8 consumers.
The consumption takes about 2 minutes. The cells in red shows a 9 request queue in one of the consumers, while other consumers had low loads - or zero load like the consumer in green.
If a random key is not a good option, what should I chose?

3. No partition, no key and leave to the Kafka round robin algorithm (drawback the round robin is internal to the Producer - meaning all producers could be sending the message to the same partition - I also tested this option and the result is below:

[image: round robin is internal to producer]
The image above shows round robin is, apparently, internal to the producer.

Do I really need to write the overall load balancing algorithm myself? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Balancing load across consumers is one of the defining features of Kafka that allows horizontal scaling.

The record key used by the producer is what allows this to work. The key defines which partition the message goes on, and any  partition will be consumed sequentially by one consumer, and so your producers should use a key strategy that produces an even spread and that ensures related messages have the same key if ordering is important (bear in mind there are other considerations around in flight requests  if strict ordering is critical).

The former is what balances the load - there is no round-robin involved in consumers, partitions are just shared out as evenly as possible among consumers in each group and they poll independently. If keys are well spread then each partition will have about the same number of records.

So, to enable effective load balancing your only responsibility is to use a good strategy for creating message keys, and define your topics with at least as many partitions as you plan to scale out consumption to.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are saying that the producers should carefully choose a key. From my understanding, this is the same as leaving load balancing to destiny... I mean, defining the partition with the key is good in some cases, especially when you need a single key to pass several times through one topic.<br>In my case the order doesn't matter. Load balancing does. I don't want to queue messages in one consumer while others are not working. Isn't there a load balance on the broker side?

Comment: Hi, your understanding is correct. As order doesn't matter then yes, choosing a balanced key so that messages are distributed evenly across partitions is what you need (actually default should be fine). All consumers in a group work in parallel independently so there is no load balancing required, the group manages consumers that join or leave the group to keep the partitions evenly distributed among members.

Comment: That's not what is really happening. My key is an UUID generated by the producer. An UUID is random, right - but it doesn't guarantee a good distribution. Chosing a key really leaves distribution to luck (actually to Kafka hash algorithm), that's not what I need. I need equal distribution on the partitions, Kafka hash algorithm doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: Ok, so that's the problem you need to address - for balanced consumption you need a key strategy that results in even spread across partitions.

Comment: With such a low throughput I think it may be a struggle to balance things evenly - the maximum messages is 30 in 5 minutes by the look of it. Most algorithms would aim to tend to a balanced spread over large numbers. With such low numbers is it necessary to have more than one consumer at the moment. I guess there must be significant processing if 30 messages in 5 minutes needs to be scaled across 8 processes?

Comment: I guess thinking about it, the design goal of Kafka is to handle high throughput, which is why its hashing approach and partitioning works. It may be worth considering if it's the right tool for lower throughput.

Comment: You are right, the processing is very heavy... This flow is repeated several times - a sequence of heavy processing microservices (ML tasks with an average of 2 minutes of high CPU/mem usage) communicating through Kafka.<br>The idea was to use Kafka as both a queue (once the producer finishes messages can enqueue in Kafka topics) and a load balancer - I see we could get a more equally distributed load balancing with a REST solution (i.e using ngninx/consul) - but we would lose the queuing capability. If only Kafka had the ability to do round robin on the server side the problem would be solved

Comment: I'm also thinking about the low throughput point of view... My feeling is that the same issue happens with high throughput applications. Considering a 1000 messages I have partitions that received 42 messages while others received 20. Not really equally distributed - I understand that the math to generate UUIDs and to calculate the hash should be on our side - but it is still based on luck. Broker side round robin on the other hand should guarantee equally distributed loads - no mater the throughput.

Comment: All good points. It always comes down to what is most important for you. In our case we have between 10s to 100s of messages per second and require related messages to be handled sequentially. Kafka works well for us in that scenario - any small imbalance is not a problem. A temporary lag on one partition has no impact, so it's the scalability with guaranteed ordering that works in our case.